# Confused about namespaces and Argument-Dependent Lookup in C++

Tags: c++, function, scope, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

I've been reading through the namespace chapter in The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup and got confused about how functions get called using Argument-Dependent Lookup. The following are code snippets from the book:

**Snippet 1**

```
namespace Chrono {
    class Date { /* ... */ };

    bool operator==(const Date&, const std::string&);

    std::string format(const Date&); // make string representation
    // ...
}

void f(Chrono::Date d, int i)
{
    std::string s = format(d); // Chrono::format()
    std::string t = format(i); // error: no format() in scope
}
```

This snippet makes sense to me since Chrono is a namespace used in the function f's arguments and therefore it is searched successfully for a format(Date) function. It also appears the function f and namespace Chrono share the same scope, which confuses me about the next snippet:

**Snippet 2**

```
namespace N {
    struct S { int i };
    void f(S);
    void g(S);
    void h(int);
}

struct Base {
    void f(N::S);
};

struct D : Base {
    void mf();
    void g(N::S x)
    {
        f(x); // call Base::f()
        mf(x); // call D::mf()
        h(1); // error: no h(int) available
    }
};
```

This makes sense to me up until the line "h(1);" Since both structs and namespace N share the same scope, why can't the function "void h(int)" be found in namespace N?

Stroustrup does go on to say that "If an argument is a member of a namespace, the associated namespaces are the enclosing namespaces." Since the argument to g is a member of namespace N, does this mean the enclosing namespace is the global namespace which does not contain a function "h(int)"? If that's the case, why wouldn't Snippet 1 fail if the enclosing namespace is the global namespace which also doesn't include a "format(Date)" function?

Thanks in advance for insight into this matter!

Comment: it is the A from ADL which is important here: **A**rgument. 1 is of type `int` which is not in `namespace N`.

Comment: ""If an argument is a member of a namespace" refers to the arguments of the function being called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADL applies based on the types of the arguments in the call itself, not the types of the parameters of the function the call may or may not be in.

In `format(d)`, `format` is looked up in `Chrono` because an argument to that call, `d`, is of the type `Chrono::Date`, and `Chrono` is an associated namespace of that type. Whether the function containing the call is `void f(Chrono::Date d, int i)` or `void f()` is irrelevant. (Obviously, in the latter case, assuming that there's a `Chrono::Date d;`.)

Comment: Thanks so much to you, Jarod, and M.M. I feel a little silly for being confused about this, but I see now that h wouldn't be found in namespace N because its argument "int" is itself not a member of namespace N. The very next sentence in the book after the one I quoted in my last paragraph was "If an argument is a built-in type, there are no associated namespaces." This was the case I should've realized applied to the 2nd case above and not the one I originally quoted.